# Why postman is sending back a 200 OK when an error occurs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, postman

I've setup some customException to return if there is error:

```
private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
{
   var error = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected

   if (ex is NotImplementedException) error = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented;
   else if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException) error = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
   else if (ex is ArgumentException) error = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
   else if (ex is ArgumentNullException) error = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

   var er = new ErrorResponse { error = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "message", ex.Message }, { "StatusCode", error.ToString() } } };

   var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(er);

   //Log to database
   Log.Error(ex, result);

   context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

   return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
}
```

So when I make a Post call from Postman, it returns with the correct error message but the status code shown on postman is 200 "OK"? What could be the reason for this?

I can provide more information regarding what's in the controller if required.

Comment: you also need to change the `Response.StatusCode` to the error value.

Comment: I believe @Catalin is suggesting right.You are returning error data as response, but not telling the response header that its an error

Comment: you need context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError

Comment: perfect thanks guys!